# How to Make Grid Component Select Filter Convert to the Like Comparison Operator in SQL

Tags: grid, filter, select

when a filter dataType  is configured as **select**. It will be converted to `filterName=selectedValue` in the final SQL. When dateType is **text**, it will be converted to`filterName like '%inputValue%'`.

My question is how to keep the filter as select but make it convert to the **like** comparison operator?